# Sensor with TTL digital output

Tags: ttl, instrumentation

I'm working with a position sensor ([Correvit Aqua L-350](http://www.flowtronic.de/uploads/media/L350A_E_01.pdf) by the manufacturer Corrsys-Datron) that gives me 0 to 5 V pulses everytime a distance (which I can choose on its software) is swept.

User manual says nothing but "Digital output: pulses - TTL".

How can I know a safe amount of current to draw out of it? I'd like to use these pulses to drive an optocoupler, so I need something around 10 mA.

Comment: That's a very hungry optocoupler. Get a better optocoupler.

Comment: 5 V output means the manual is lying about the output type, and it's most likely actually a CMOS output. Call tech support for the device and ask them how much current it can drive. Or take the lid off and see what IC is actually producing the output.

Comment: I tried to make contact with the manufacturer. Not sure if they're going to answer. That's such an expensive sensor, I won't risk myself looking inside. Anyway, thanks so much.

Comment: @Eric in that case, having the model of the sensor as part of the question surely won't hurt – I was just assuming that this was self-built or simply impossible to buy, so that no-one else would have knowledge of it, but now that you say it's "expensive", I feel like it's probably something that someone on here might have already have encountered.

Comment: It's a Correvit Aqua L-350 by the manufacturer Corrsys-Datron. If someone has some knowledge of this specific device, it would be very fortunate

Comment: That two-page sheet is all there is for a manual on this device??? Without hope for additional help from the manufacturer (have you called them by phone?) and without being willing to open it up and see, it would be nice to first perform some tests on the output. Is there a reason you cannot use the analog output (0-10 V)?

Answer (score 4):

"TTL" can mean that the output behaves exactly the same as with devices in the <strike>good</strike> old [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) logic family. This would imply that the output is specified to sink up to 16 mA and to source up to 0.4 mA (and that the high level is nowhere near 5 V, but typically 3.4 V).

However, "TTL" can also mean "5 V CMOS". This would imply that the voltage levels are rail-to-rail, and that the possible source and sink currents are symmetrical. But there is no standard for "TTL" CMOS currents.

Nowadays, very few devices are still made in bipolar logic, so "TTL" is likely to mean the second case.
So you have to look up the current in a *real* datasheet. (Which might not exist, or your merchant might not tell you about it.)

---

Note: many digital optocouplers (e.g., the H11L1) do not need more than 1.6 mA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.On the oscilloscope, I saw a signal that went really near to 5 V, around 4.8 or so. 

I'm using a 4n25, maybe changing for another optocoupler would be a good idea. But if 0.4 mA is the max current to be drawn out of the sensor, 1.6 would still be too much.

Comment: You can still use the sensor to **sink** the LED of your optocouple.

Comment: @Eric 4.8 V means that you have CMOS, so you don't know the design limit. But a voltage drop of 0.2 V means that you should be OK.

Comment: 0.2V drop defines the source resistance  for TTL it is normal to have a fanout of 10.  when using 1.6mA as a TTL equivalent low current load.  ESR calculations are handy.

Answer (score 0):

"TTL Levels" mean that the output is defined by TTL levels but is always driven by CMOS these days. But since CMOS levels are not universal, they still use TTL even though using CMOS to drive it.  TTL (Voh) means anything from 2 to 5V depending on load current but CMOS 74HCxxx CMOS at 5V is 50 (nom) ~100 Ohms (max) RdsOn so you can include this with your current limit calculations for 1.2V (@25'C) IR LED drop to choose R.  One must also factor MTBF and LED reduces intensity after 50kh perhaps 50% for example.  SO there is no 1 fix optimal current.

**It is always a question of reliability, environmental stress and design margin specs.**

**- always consult specs and create design specs from that.**

- roughly e.g.  (4.5V- 1.5V) / 2mA = 1.8 kOhms
  ,  (LED Vmax @ 0'C)
- 2nd e.g. load current 5V/10k = 0.5mA with CTR = 10% use 5mA input thus (5V- 1.15V)/5mA = 770 ohms,  (typ @ 25'C)

Compare to CMOS 50~100 ohm  source impedance, 770 ohms load will reduce Voh ~10% to 4.5V +/-5~10%

Depending on the load capacitance and Pulse width and thus dV/dt=I/C  , you can use the Current Transfer Ratio e.g. 10% min. @ 10mA  to determine input current to supply needed output current.

THe  H11L1  may cost 2x~3x ( $0.25/5k) as much but has a open drain output and can use lower current, but still 1.2mA may be marginal for EM immunity, so it is still rated at 10mA which lowers circuit impedance. EMI immunity from nearby dI/dt increases with drive levels.  1.4~ 2mA may be OK for you or not, depending on system noise.

### So what is ideal current?

depends on CTR of IC,  load RC=T ,  immunity and pulse width.

- The calculations are no more complicated  ( in rationale) than using a NPN open collector switch except hFE <1.

Comment: The calculations are no more complicated ( in rationale) than using a NPN open collector switch except hFE <1.

I get it. My purpose is to use to use this signal to switch a Vcc of 24 V, so I can use it as the input of a PLC. My first choice would be an NPN open collector, but electrical isolation provided by the optocoupler is necessary. 

Now that I know that the TTL output I'm working with is driven by CMOS, I'm in a better position to establish a "safe" value of current?

Comment: yes knowing tolerance of RdsOn 50~100 is negligible compared to Rs. and Vcc tolerance, so SNR tolerance with dI/dt coupling and impedance ratio of source to Rs at frequency of rise time tolerance for glitches. So if induction impedance of nearfield say \$\omega\$ L /Rs of cable << I(f) interference/Idc ( signal).. Depends on twisted pair, shielding, glitch sensitivity to system. etc. When designers give up on trying to calc. Optimal for susceptibility  they test it with PLT, ESD etc. then choose immunity current threshold. depends on CMRR of cable, best case is max current.  marginal in min

Comment: "safe" depends on your DVT specs for immunity and MTBF and error rate

Comment: H11L1 is better with hysteresis for EMI immunity or any open collector with RC filter to limit BW Hz on input or output.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few random thoughts:

1. I wonder why you can't consider using their \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$10\:\textrm{V}\$ analog output, their CAN interface, their RS-232 interface, or their USB interface.
2. I'm surprised you don't have access to a user manual and instead only seem to have a two-page sales sheet on it.
3. I'm surprised you cannot seem to contact the manufacturer (or an appropriate representative sales company) for such an expensive device.
4. The sheet of information you did provide seems to say that it provides between 1 and 1000 pulses per ***minute***? This would seem to mean anything from \$60\:\textrm{ms}\$ to \$60\:\textrm{s}\$ between pulses? Meaning it takes a full minute to get a reading? That surprises me.

Well, those are my surprises and thoughts going into it.

You want to use an opto-coupler but all you know is that the output is given as "TTL." You've put a voltmeter on it and found \$4.8\:\textrm{V}\$ (and by implication, I guess it is fair to say that you also were able to find a voltage close to zero, too.) Before considering a minimal design, it would be nice to know more about the output. And this would mean doing some verification testing to determine exactly the kind of output and it's current compliances, slew rate, etc. But given your other comments I'm going to assume that process would be a whole other set of instructions and beyond the scope I want to engage here. Easier to just assume a light load.

So:

- Assume the output can sink or source up to \$50\:\mu\textrm{A}\$. This is light enough to be fairly certain about it. Your voltmeter loads it less, but it is reasonable to assume that the output can drive perhaps 10 times the load of a voltmeter as a minimum. So I think this is fair.
- You want to drive an opto-coupler.
- You have access to a good \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ power supply rail that may be accessed and used for the receiver output side of the opto-coupler.
- You are using the vehicle's battery/alternator system, directly or indirectly, to power the unit. It's sheet says, \$10\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$28\:\textrm{V}\$. So, you want something that will use that power rail voltage range successfully for the emitter side of the opto-coupler.

A simpler answer to this may be the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpQOTY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The basic idea here is to operate \$Q_1\$ as an emitter follower, so that you can take advantage of the full current gain (\$\beta\$) for the device and significantly lower the loading on your device's output. \$R_1\$ should set about \$10\:\textrm{mA}\$ for driving the opto-coupler's emitter (which is more than enough.) You could increase the value of \$R_1\$ a bit (perhaps double it), depending on the specific opto-coupler device manufacturer you use. But with a \$\beta\approx 200\$ for the BJT, the loading should be on the order of \$50\:\mu\textrm{A}\$. Very light.

The opto-coupler needs a pull-up. That's \$R_2\$. In this case, I don't think you need to use a stronger pull-up. So I think that value should be more than strong enough. But the value isn't critical, so feel free to get something nearby.

The \$V_{CAR}\$ voltage is whatever you are using to power the device. If this is a separate conditioned power supply, that's fine. Since your device requires at least \$10\:\textrm{V}\$ to power it and no more than \$28\:\textrm{V}\$, the above circuit will work fine regardless of what you do so long as you just use the same supply rail here (left side.)

That should do it. The 6N137 does require the \$+5\:\textrm{V}\$ supply from your MCU side, but I think you probably have that. And I'm pretty sure it won't matter what kind of output is present. TTL and CMOS will both drive the above and given your actual measurement of about \$4.8\:\textrm{V}\$ with a meter, I think it will be fine regardless. It certainly will be safe to try.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.

Some points I didn't talk about on my question:

1) My goal is to make the output signal as input signal for a PLC, which needs something around 24 V for its logical high level. 

2) The PLC is my only "measuring" tool, and it has only analog and digital inputs, and RS485 interface, hence I'm not considering CAN, USB or RS232 for my purposes. Analog signal is speed.

3) I do have the user manual, not just the datasheet. But not much is said about the digital output besides "TTL".

Comment: 4)I've sent an email to the company that took over Corrsys Datron, which was the manufacturer for the device when it was bought. 

5) The digital is 1...1000 pulses per meter.

So, your circuit is really a nice solution for my problem. I do not have 5 Vcc available, only a battery bank. 6n137 has a maximum of 7 Vcc, but I think 4N25 could handle my 24 V, and that would be the digital input for the PLC.

The only problem is that I simulated this circuit with Multisim and the current on the sensor, although having a mean of around 25 uA appears to reach positive and negative peaks of 13 mA

Comment: @Eric Those positive and negative peaks are very, very short, aren't they? (Those you see in the simulator are due to real capacitances [tiny, though] and an unrealistic model otherwise supplied to Spice.) They won't be a problem here. Use the usual capacitance bypass for the opto-isolator, in practice. But you cannot use the 6N137, as you say. So. Perhaps the 4N25 would be a good choice here. Do you already know how to arrange the schematic for one?

Comment: Yes, they are very short in time (5ns). Looking closely at the waves, I saw that the peaks appear only on the rising time of the output. So, as you said, they are related to capacitances.

Now, for the real case, I think I should be concerned with those peaks, shouldn't I? Because the capacitances are always present, and the peak currents may be harmful to the sensor. Not to sure if it's a good solution, but adding a 1 mH inductor in series to the digital out smooths the peaks to 300 uA (then they decay as damped oscillations).

Comment: When you say "use the usual capacitance bypass for the optoiscolator in practice", I don't know exactly what you mean, because it's the first time I'm working with optocouplers. Where should I connect this capacitor? Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: @Eric You'd need the bypass for the 6N137. But not so much for the 4N25. Don't worry about the spikes. They are in the simulator and will exist (differently) in reality. But they are irrelevant here. No inductors!